# How can I speed up pages that have a lot of php to load?

Tags: php, performance

Some pages are taking a long time to load. I assume its from all the PHP - using a lot of `fopen` and `fget` statements. What can I do to make these pages load more quickly?

Comment: Use `fopen` and `fget` less, or buy faster connection.

Comment: what can't you get from my words? If `fopen` is an issue - avoid of using it. It is pretty obvious for me.

Comment: They're likely your bottleneck - that's what he meant. This question is to vague to answer in any case. What are you using fopen and fget for? What is a "lot of PHP"? What's your script doing?

Comment: What's the network speed of the client you're using? or is it taking too long running the script from the server ? What kind o files are you opening ? Answer all these and you shall receive a solution/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) to profile your code and refactor it.
2. Use a [PHP accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators) to cache bytecode, like [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/).
3. Break your page up into smaller chunks and use AJAX to pull them in all at once
4. Use an HTTP Accelerator like [varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/).
5. Cache bits of the page (or the whole page) any other way.

Comment: Thanks this is the first reasonable answer

Comment: "reasonable" but unfortunately has nothing to do with the question itself: "how to make a lot of `fopen` faster"

Answer (score 3):

Implement aggressive caching.​

Comment: The next question will be: "How can I invalidate caches. My pages always contain obsolete information" ))

Comment: cache on write and when to invalidate caches? ;-) If he always need actual data - cache will not improve remote call performance.

Answer (score 2):

A database may be faster if you're using a lot of file resources as a data layer solution.

Alternatively, consider caching your pages, beginning with client-side HTTP caching and considering server-side caching later.

Beyond that, more details are needed (at which stage we're basically consulting for you).

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to perform a lot of remote calls with `fopen` - I would suggest you to create some kind of queues and implement some worker, that can work with threads in simultaneous manner.

So in your php code you put the "tasks" to the queue and waiting for the answers. In the same time fast and performant daemon (written in c/c++/python or whatever language that supports threads well) reads the tasks from queue and puts the responses into another queue.